# curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate for More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Tags: linux, redhat, elk, centos8

curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
error: https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch: import read failed(2).

Comment: I think we agree that this is an error message.  Are you unclear on what it means?  Are you unsure what to do next?  Can you tell us what you were doing to cause it?  Can you tell us what you've tried to fix the problem?  Just posting an error message without context isn't very helpful.

Comment: What are you trying to do or how are you getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to solve this problem:

- Ignore the problem and add -k to the command line. This is not recommended.
- Download the latest cacert.pem file. Specify this file using the command line option `–cacert <path>/cacert.pem`.
- Download the latest cacert.pem file. Set the environment variable `set CURL_CA_BUNDLE=<path>/cacert.pem`.
- On Windows put `curl-ca-bundle.crt` in your path. The bundle is part of the Windows download.

[Download cacert.pem for all platforms](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem).

[Curl documentation on this issue](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html).